# Get first entry in sorted output columns

Tags: bash, scripting

Not sure exactly how to phrase this but I have output that returns information sorted neatly in columns separated by what appears to be tabs or spaces

```
$ pactl list short sink-inputs

10  1   6   protocol-native.c   float32le 2ch 44100Hz
12  1   34  protocol-native.c   s16le 2ch 44100Hz
```

I want to return the result from the first column (10)

```
myvar=$(pactl list short sink-inputs | grep float32le |  ?  )
```

I know there is a bash command for this but I cannot think what to search

Answer (score 3):

`awk` can replace `grep` as well and will work with both spaces and tabs

```
myvar=$(pactl list short sink-inputs | awk '/float32le/{print $1}')
```

Answer (score 2):

The bash tool `cut` is pretty much designed for this

```
myvar=$(pactl list short sink-inputs | grep float32le | cut -f1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `sed` (and, as with `awk`, cut out the grep). `sed` is about
half the size of `awk` and should execute (marginally?) faster if that matters
to you.

Being a longer line it takes longer to type though, so you may lose any time
you gain (and then some) :P I would therefore personally use the `awk` or `cut`
method, unless you're putting it in a script and/or are dealing with a large
dataset.

```
myvar="$(pactl list short sink-inputs|sed -n '/float32le/s/^\([^ \t]*\).*float32le.*$/\1/p')"
```

Broken down, this is:

```
sed -n '                                            '
```

`-n` tells sed not to output anything unless explicitly requested to

```
        /float32le/
```

Search for *float32le*

```
                   s/
```

When found, we'll substitute...

```
                     ^                        $
```

from the beginning of the line, to the end...

```
                      \(       \)
```

but remember (as "item" (matching sub-expression) *1*)...

```
                        [^ \t]*
```

everything up until the first space or tab.

```
                                   float32le
```

In order to do our substitute of the line, it must contain *float32le*...

```
                                 .*         .*
```

surrounded by **anything**.

```
                                               /\1
```

Replace the entire line we're substituting, with the "item" *1* we remembered earlier.

```
                                                  /p
```

In the event we did do the above substitution, we'll print out the result.